# I used graalvm to compile the spring boot3 project for jdk17. module opens unnamed

Tags: java, build, graalvm-native-image

There seems to be no way to add jvm parameters to enable anonymous modules to access java.base/java.lang. I tried to add --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED, but the binary that was compiled into graalvm still reported an error. The way I compile is with something like native iamge-jar[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDBq5.png)

I hope that the binary file compiled by the way of native image-jar can run normally without error